# ADODB Connection - Header text not extracted & read-only issue

Tags: vba, excel, connection-string, adodb

I am delving into the world of VBA data connections, and would appreciate some assistance. The code below is what I have so far, but there are a couple of oddities I can't figure out.

```
Sub sbADO()
    Dim sSQLQry As String
    Dim ReturnArray
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String

    DBPath = "C:\USERS\NAME\DOCUMENTS\VBA Work\Data Source.xlsx"
    sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"
    Conn.Open sconnect

    sSQLQry = "SELECT * From [Sheet1$]"
    mrs.Open sSQLQry, Conn
    Sheet3.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset mrs
    mrs.Close
    Conn.Close
End Sub
```

This code works, however:

1. The data pulled in doesn't include Row1 of the dataset (so the headers aren't pulled in)
2. If the source workbook 'Data Source.xlsx' is open. The code will cause the workbook to open again but in read-only mode. Can this be avoided?
3. Can the connection string be edited so that the source file is never locked out? ie. queried in Read-Only mode other users can open it whilst the query is being completed?

Any help is appreciated
Thanks
Caleeco

Comment: The schema metadata is *never* part of the result set. Iterate the `Fields` collection.

Comment: What's the problem with opening the workbook in read-only mode? The file is locked for editing by another process/user - you *can't* acquire a write lock on it. Aren't you *reading* from it anyway? Does it still pop a message if you specify `Mode=read;` in the connection string?

Comment: @Mat'sMug thanks for the replies. Ah ok, i'm very new to dealing with recordsets & connection strings. Two problems here. If I pause the code after executing this line `Conn.Open sconnect`, then try to open the source file `Data Source.xlsx` i get the `File is Locked by Another User` warning message. This is undesirable as I have many people on the network that need Write access to that source file. Not too concerned about a second instance being opened as `Read-only` if someone ALREADY has the file locked out as I can close it with VBA after.

Comment: In response to your edit. I tried changing the conn string to `sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';Mode=Read;ReadOnly=True;"` but still get the same problem of locking out this file while the query is executed.

Comment: That's normal and very very very desirable behavior on Windows. I thought the problem was that your macro was popping up the read-only warning when the file was already opened by someone else.

Comment: Sorry let me explain the two scenarios a bit better. **Scenario 1:** Code is run. Nobody on the network has the file open. Code locks file whilst being run. No other users can access file at this time. The source file does not open visually on the screen (this is desirable). Can excel not query a read-only version of the sheet? **Scenario 2:** Code is run. Someone on the network has the file open. The file is opened in read-only mode in another instance of Excel on my screen (the code runner). Read-Only source file remains open once connection is closed.

Comment: `Set mrs = Nothing` and then `Set Conn = Nothing` after you close both, that should put the final nail in these objects' coffins. TBH the best solution is to put that data where it belongs: in a database. Even MS-Access would do.

Comment: Thanks always a good idea to free up some memory! That doesnt resolve my two problem cases unfortunately. I would love to use a proper database, however, MS Access is hard to come by at my place of work; hence I'm stuck with excel!

Comment: You literally have a legit business case for setting up a proper database here. Surely someone has an Office license with Access that they're not using, or there's a file server somewhere that could run SQL Server Express (free). Excel is not a database, and this is exactly the kinds of problems you run into when you treat it like it's one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub sbADO()
  Dim sSQLQry As String
  Dim ReturnArray
  Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String,i as integer

  'DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
  DBPath = "C:\USERS\NAME\DOCUMENTS\VBA Work\Data Source.xlsx"
  sconnect= "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""" & _
     DBPath & """;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX = 1"""

  Conn.Open sconnect

  sSQLQry = "SELECT * From [Sheet1$]"
  mrs.Open sSQLQry, Conn
  if rs.recordcount>0 then 
     rs.movefirst
     for i=0 to rs.fields.count-1
       'read here the headers and add them to your sheet in row 1
       Sheet3.Cells(1, i + 1) =rs.Fields(i).Name
     next
  end if
  Sheet3.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset mrs
  mrs.Close
  Conn.Close
End Sub
```